# Delete rpm from rpm

Tags: rpm

I want to create one rpm with rpmbuild which can remove some others rpm in system forcefully.

How can i integrate rpm -e --nodeps packagename.rpm command in specfile?

Comment: Sounds risky.  Just sayin'

Comment: I know which rpm must be deleted in order to install new rpm. I just want to delete them automatically when new rpm installs.

Answer (score 2):

This should generally only be done when a software package is being renamed. If you try to use this to remove *other* software, you will break someone's system, and administrators will curse you forever...

In this case, use the `Obsoletes` directive in your spec file.

For instance, in an example package `wireshark.spec`:

```
Name: wireshark
Obsoletes: ethereal
```

(The old name of Wireshark was Ethereal; this made the package update work properly when the software was renamed several years ago.)